# If $Y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ diverges, is $Y$ a random variable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, terminology, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be random variables. By definition, a random variable is a function from the probability space to $\mathbb{R}$. If $Y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ diverges, is it correct to call $Y$ a random variable? Would it be correct, sloppy, imprecise,  or incorrect?

In particular, if I want to take the expected value of such a series before knowing whether it is finite or not, is it imprecise to say that 'I take expectation'? Should I just say 'I integrate'?

Answer (score 1):

Usually convergence, and existence of a finite expected value, are things that happen with probability either $1$ or $0$.  In the first case it is a matter of convention whether you include Divergent as a probability $0$ outcome in the range of $Y$, and in the second case talking about the divergent quantity is asking the wrong question, such as "what is the expected arc length of a Brownian motion sample path".

Comment: The set $[(X_n)\ \text{converges}]$ is always measurable.